# What is the definition of "in and of..."

Tags: grammar, legalese

What does "in and of..." mean in the sentence below?

> While resource scarcity **in and of** itself is not considered a major factor in igniting conflict...

How is it different if I just change it to "of" only?

> While resource scarcity **of** itself is not considered a major factor in igniting conflict.

What should I call this grouping of words ("in and of")? Are there anymore words that are used similarly?

Comment: The idiomatic *in and of itself* is really just meaningless tautology, similar to *in no way, shape, or form*. You can quite reasonably discard ***in and of*** completely, or just keep ***in*** or ***of*** (or replace with ***by***). None of this changes the meaning (even the word ***itself*** contributes nothing apart from emphasis here).

Answer (score 7):

*In itself* and *of itself* are loan translations from Latin *in se* and *per se*. In the fields of philosophy and law these have very precise technical meanings, and the combined phrase *in and of itself* should be left unmodified when used by an expert speaking of matters in those fields.

In any other context, *in and of itself* is a stock phrase adopted probably from legal discourse. It can be reduced to one or the other:

- *in itself*, meaning “by its own nature, inherently” ... English grammar is not in itself boring, it is only made to appear so by teachers.
- *of itself*, meaning “through its own operation, by its own effort” ... An English verbform usually cannot of itself fix relationships in time; it must be interpreted by the context in which it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in and of itself means by itself.